# Como actualizar R en Rstudio para Linux

Tags: r

Hola chicos estoy empezando a aprender R recien lo instalé pero necesito instalar algunos paquetes (ggplot2, swirl, lattice, car, flmport y tseries.) pero tengo problemas para instalar car, buscando información leí que car necesita la versión más reciente de R (la versión que tengo es 3.5.3 fue la que se me instalo con el comando **$ sudo dnf install R**)
Así que estoy tratando de actualizarlo utilizando **install.packages("installr")** y me aparece esto

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (installr)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmptEVaUs/downloaded_packages’
```

seguido de **library(installr)** y me sale

```
Welcome to installr version 0.23.2

More information is available on the installr project website:
https://github.com/talgalili/installr/

Contact: <tal.galili@gmail.com>
Suggestions and bug-reports can be submitted at: https://github.com/talgalili/installr/issues

            To suppress this message use:
            suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(installr))
```

después uso **updateR** pero antes de terminar de escribirlo me aparece un recuadro de emergencia diciendo *Error Retrieving Help. R code execution error* si completo de escribir **updateR()** me aparecen aún más errores

```
Error in fetch(key) : 
  lazy-load database '/home/jorgesmartinez/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/installr/help/installr.rdb' is corrupt
> updateR()
Error in winDialog(type = "ok", message = message_text) : 
  no se pudo encontrar la función "winDialog"
Además: Warning message:
In get.installed.R.folders() :
  Could not find any R installation on your system. (You might have installed your R version on 'c:\R' without sub folders...
```

¿Existe alguna otra forma de actualizarlo o estoy haciendo algo mal? También he intentado con **install.packages("installr", dependencies = TRUE)** pero me marca error al instalar el paquete

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: `installr` según la documentación: `The installr package offers a set of R functions for the installation and updating of software (currently, only on Windows OS)`, o sea, en Linux olvidate de este método. Vas a tener que recurrir a los procedimientos propios  del SO para poder actualizar R. También recuerda que existe la posibilidad de trabajar con Rsdtudio en la nube: https://rstudio.cloud/